# How can I can I center a row of relatively centered <div>s in a container width of 100%

Tags: css, hover, css-position, css-transitions, center

I am trying to center a row of relatively centered divs that contain images that have hover transitions that change into another image.

In the process of making getting the hover transition to work, I positioned the containers for each div as position: relative.

I'm trying to get the row to center as the window browser grows smaller to make it responsive. The behavior that happens is so strange though. The image as the browser window gets too small to accommodate the row of images will jump to the second row, but it will stop a little left of screen, but not center.

Does anyone have a solution or understanding of why this is happening? I ideally would like the image that jumps to the second row to center.

Here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/4kfbh018/

HTML

```
<div class="center-logo">
<div class="nbc-container">
<a href="#">
    <div class="nbc press">
        <span></span>
    </div>
</a>
</div>

<div class="npr-container">
<a href="#">
    <div class="npr press">
        <span></span>
    </div>
</a>
</div>

<div class="washington-container">
<a href="#">
    <div class="washington press">
        <span></span>
    </div>
</a>
</div>

<div class="bbc-container">
 <a href="#">
    <div class="bbc press">
        <span></span>
    </div>
 </a>
</div>

<div class="forbes-container">
<a href="#">
    <div class="forbes press">
        <span></span>
    </div>
</a>
</div>

<div class="cnet-container">
<a href="#">
    <div class="cnet press">
        <span></span>
    </div>
</a>
</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.center-logo {
margin: 0 auto;
height: 99px;
width: 100%;
}

.press {
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; 
}

.press:hover span {
    opacity: 1;
}

.nbc {
    background-image: url('http://www.yodamark.net/files/7114/0570/5786/nbc.jpg');
    height: 79px;
    width: 79px;

}

.nbc-container {
    height: 79px;
    margin: 10px 10px;
    width: 79px;
    float: left;
}

.nbc span {
    height: 79px;
    width: 79px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; 
    background-image: url('http://www.yodamark.net/files/4114/1168/9420/nbc-b.jpg');
    opacity: 0;
    transition: linear .2s, box-shadow linear .2s;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
} 


.npr {
    height: 41px;
    width: 109px;
    background-image: url('http://www.yodamark.net/files/6414/0570/5787/npr.jpg');
    height: 41px;
    width: 109px;
}

.npr-container {
    height: 41px;
    margin: 25px 10px 0 10px;
    width: 109px;
    float: left;
}

.npr span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; 
    background-image: url('http://www.yodamark.net/files/6414/1168/8919/npr-b.jpg');
    height: 41px;
    width: 109px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: linear .2s, box-shadow linear .2s;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
} 

.washington {
    background-image: url('http://www.yodamark.net/files/6514/0570/5787/wapo.jpg');
    height: 34px;
    width: 232px;
}

.washington-container {
    float: left;
    height: 41px;
    margin: 25px 10px 0 10px;
    width: 232px;
}

.washington span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; 
    background-image: url('http://www.yodamark.net/files/6214/1168/8864/wapo-b.jpg');
    height: 34px;
    width: 232px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: linear .2s, box-shadow linear .2s;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
} 

.bbc {
    background-image: url('http://www.yodamark.net/files/2914/0570/5785/bbc.jpg');
    height: 35px;
    width: 186px;
}

.bbc-container {    
    height: 35px;
    margin: 25px 10px 0 10px;
    width: 186px;
    float: left;
}

.bbc span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; 
    background-image: url('http://www.yodamark.net/files/1314/1168/9450/bbc-b.jpg');
    height: 35px;
    width: 186px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: linear .2s, box-shadow linear .2s;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
}

.forbes {
    background-image: url('http://www.yodamark.net/files/2614/0570/5786/forbes.jpg');
    height: 38px;
    width: 117px;
}

.forbes-container {
    height: 38px;
    margin: 25px 10px 0 10px;
    width: 117px;
    float: left;
}

.forbes span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; 
    background-image: url('http://www.yodamark.net/files/1514/1168/9431/forbes-b.jpg');
    height: 38px;
    width: 117px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: linear .2s, box-shadow linear .2s;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
}

.cnet {
    background-image: url('http://www.yodamark.net/files/5314/0570/5785/cnet.jpg');
    height: 83px;
    width: 85px;
}

.cnet-container {
    height: 83px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    width: 85px;
    float: left;
}

.cnet span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; 
    background-image: url('http://www.yodamark.net/files/8014/1168/9440/cnet-b.jpg');
    height: 83px;
    width: 85px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: linear .2s, box-shadow linear .2s;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No Floats**

Use `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left`.

`text-align:center` has no effect on floated elements other than centering the content inside of them.

You can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4kfbh018/1/) where I overrode your css.

Comment: Thank you filever10!! I've been stuck on this forever!

Comment: Actually, I realize the solution does not work, because the hover effect does not work. Do you have a fix for this?

Comment: I found a solve for the hover effect. I just put the container of the image as position: relative, so that both the image and the hover image are positioned absolutely and not going off screen after hovering. Your inline solution still works. thanks!!!